# How to order tasks and subtasks with make?

Tags: gnu-make

I am using GNU make as a tool to perform some tasks.
Suppose I have two tasks, A and B, which have subtasks.
I must execute task B (and its subtasks) before task A.

I have this minimum working example

```
all: task1

task1: task2    

task1: task1.1
    @echo task1

task1.1: task1.2
    @echo task1.1

task1.2:
    @echo task1.2

task2: task2.1
    @echo task2

task2.1: task2.2
    @echo task2.1

task2.2:
    @echo task2.2
```

Anyway, this does not work as expected since the output is this:

```
task1.2
task1.1
task2.2
task2.1
task2
task1
```

Instead, I would like to have

```
task2.2
task2.1
task2
task1.2
task1.1
task1
```

just by specifing the dependency task1: task2, i.e. subtasks shall not be involved.

I've been able to obtain this behavior putting task1: task2 under task1: task1.1, but it is recommended to design dependencies in such a way they do not rely on their order.

Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*order-only* prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html). Since you want to run `task2` before `task1.2`, you can add `| task2` as ordering prerequisite for `task1.2`.

```
all: task1

task1: task2    

task1: task1.1
    @echo task1

task1.1: task1.2
    @echo task1.1

task1.2: | task2
    @echo task1.2

task2: task2.1
    @echo task2

task2.1: task2.2
    @echo task2.1

task2.2:
    @echo task2.2
```

Comment: The same might be obtained without order-only prerequisites just by having task1.2: task2

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer my own question.
This works as expected:

```
all: task1

task1.depends: task2

tasks1 = task1.1 task1.2

tasks2 = task2.1 task2.2

task1: task1.1
    @echo task1

task1.1: task1.2
    @echo task1.1

task1.2:
    @echo task1.2

task1.depends:

$(tasks1): task1.depends

task2: task2.1
    @echo task2

task2.1: task2.2
    @echo task2.1

task2.2:
    @echo task2.2

task2.depends:

$(tasks2): task2.depends
```

Do you have any suggestion to improve it?